# How to reach my controller/method on laravel?

Tags: laravel

**ERROR ON CONSOLE:** http://localhost/upload 404 (Not Found)

I'm not reaching the controller/method doing a post call from a form.

I'm trying to upload the user's files and then save it on a folder inside my proyect.

It was working but idk why not now.

```
<form action="upload" id="upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        <input type="file" name="file[]" multiple> <br /><br />
                        {{ csrf_field() }}
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">    
                    </form> 

                    <script>
                        var form = document.getElementById('upload');
                        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

                        form.addEventListener('submit', function(e){
                            e.preventDefault();
                            var formdata = new FormData(form);

                            request.open('post', '/upload');
                            request.addEventListener("load", transferComplete);
                            request.send(formdata);
                        });

                        function transferComplete(data){
                            console.log(data.currentTarget.response);
                        }
                    </script>
```

My routes are

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('auth.login');
});

Route::post('upload', 'UploadController@upload');
Route::post('upload2', 'UploadController@upload2');


Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
Route::get('change-password', 'Auth\UpdatePasswordController@index')->name('password.form');
Route::post('change-password', 'Auth\UpdatePasswordController@update')->name('password.update');
```

UPLOAD CONTROLLER:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

use Storage;

class UploadController extends Controller
{
    public function upload(Request $request){
        $files = $request->file('file');

        if(!empty($files)){
            foreach ($files as $file) {
                Storage::put('xml/'.$file->getClientOriginalName(), file_get_contents($file));
            }
        }
        include base_path('storage/app/TAYCO-procesa-XML_emitidos.php');
    }
    public function upload2(Request $request){
        $files = $request->file('file2');

        if(!empty($files)){
            foreach ($files as $file) {
                Storage::put('xml/'.$file->getClientOriginalName(), file_get_contents($file));
            }
        }
        include base_path('storage/app/TAYCO-procesa-XML_recibidos.php');
    }
}
```

Comment: You better show us your `UploadController`.

Comment: sorry about that, added dude!

Comment: Does a regular form submission work instead of using AJAX (by removing `<script>...</script>`)? If you change `Route::post('upload', ..` to `Route::get('upload', ..` and then browse to `http://localhost/upload`, do you still get the 404? What is the output of `php artisan route:list`? Do you have any interfering middleware?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use a `get` route to show the form, and a `post` route to post the form.
Add this line to your route:

**web.php**

```php
Route::get('upload', 'UploadController@index');
```

Add this function to your `UploadController`:

**UploadController.php**

```php
public function index() {
    return view('the_name_of_your_view_file_with_its_path');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i'm not getting problems to show the forms, they are in /Home (Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');)

My problem is when i submit the form and call the /upload route

Comment: You are calling the `/upload` route and you MUST have a `Route::get('upload', ...)` in your routes otherwise, you will get a `404` error. You have to do it like what I wrote, the upload should not be in the `HomeController`.